# Loading images in dynamic iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an issue where I'm creating an iframe dynamically (so there's no URL), and executing a print on that frame. The first time I hit print (in ff) it doesn't show the images, because they haven't loaded. Is it possible using jQuery or vanilla JS to force the print to wait for the iframe to load all of the images inside of it? My relevant code looks like:

```
render: function (data, $el) {
    var index = $('a.myframe').index($el);
    $el.attr('data-print-frame', 'print-frame-' + index);
    this.populateTemplate(data, index);
    this.printData('print-frame-' + index, index);

    return this;
},
populateTemplate: function(data, index) {
    if(!$('iframe[name=print-frame-' + index + ']').length) {
        var iframehtml = '';
        var iframe = $('<iframe class="print-frame" name="print-frame-' + index + '" />');
        $('#content-area').append(iframe);
        var $stylesheets = $('*[rel=stylesheet]').clone();
        var inlineStyles = '';
        $stylesheets.each(function(i,e) {
            $stylesheets[i].href = $stylesheets[i].href;
            $stylesheets[i].href = $stylesheets[i].href.replace('debug=true', 'debug=false');
            $.ajax({
                url: $stylesheets[i].href,
                dataType: 'text',
                async: false,
                success: function(styledata) {
                    inlineStyles += styledata;
                }
            });
        });
        iframehtml = '<div class="print"><div id="wrapper">' + this.template(data) + '</div></div>';
        iframe[0].contentDocument.head.innerHTML = '<style type="text/css">' + inlineStyles + '</style>';
        iframe[0].contentDocument.body.innerHTML = iframehtml;
    }
},
printData: function(printId) {
    //this is the part that is not working
    $('iframe[name="' + printId + '"]').load(function() {
        window.frames[printId].focus();
        window.frames[printId].print();
    });
    //this is the part that is not working
}
```

So the appended HTML has images in it that I need to show on the first click of the iframe. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to use the frame document onready event.

```
 printData: function(printId) {

        $(window.frames[printId].document).ready(function() {
            window.frames[printId].focus();
            window.frames[printId].print();
        });

    }
```

Comment: The standard document ready function doesn't wait for images, so I'm pretty sure that a specific frame's ready function won't wait for images either.